Subterranean river drainage
In my worldbuilding project, there is a large lake and associated river basin which I have planned currently to drain through a subterranean river and reemerge downstream. I really like the idea but because the river drains about 5-7k m³ of water per second (estimates based on earth rivers with similar rainfall and basin areas) and I don't know if having water drain this way is realistic or sustainable over a long period of time, I thought it would be wise to ask.
The area is a mix of sedimentary and flood basalt rock. A shallow sea was there at one point, leaving a layer of limestone with very shallow basin topography over relatively impermeable and erosion resistant substrate rock. I've included a rough, somewhat ugly illustration of the later geological processes, which I explain below. 
The inland sea later recedes, and the basin erodes a pretty deep canyon in the process through which to drain, shrinking the inland sea into a series of lakes. The area experiences a lot of undercutting and cave formation in the limestone.
Later, this area experiences a volcanic intrusion which raises the topography and covers the land in a layer of flood basalt, which also spills into the canyon. A substantial amount of water is trapped this way both in the canyon area, surrounding caves, and in the drainage basin, which does overflow a bit and find another path briefly (the erosion here later helps define a separate river basin once water level drops). Through a combination of preexisting cave systems, geologic disturbance, pressure from the superheated, trapped water, and acidification of that water as a result of the volcanic activity, a continuous route does eventually form that allows drainage, which is expanded by erosion over time. Undercutting from the new point of ingress allows the original opening of the canyon to eventually link up, and that point of ingress is later covered up by new volcanic activity, allowing a surface river to flow over the ingress area later and empty into the lake.
My question is, would a subterranean river with the aforementioned geology be sustainable as a long term geographic feature, without causing the lake to change level beyond a small (<5-10m) initial drop? By which I mean to ask if such a river would be able to form and then stay around, without changing volume or water level for the lake, for a period of several tens of thousands of years. Sidenote here, but initial water level drop is fine, what I want is for it to stabilize into one system.
Things like substrate rock topology and composition, degree of volcanic acidification, cave-ins, and preexisting cave systems can all be assumed to support this end result, within reason (i.e. cave ins could limit inflow after a certain drop in water level to stop the whole lake from draining, or it is okay to assume the substrate halts some more rapid erosion), and the river does not experience much seasonal variation in its ~5-7k m³/s flow rate.
Let me know if additional info would be useful, and I might be able to provide it! Thanks!
Here also is a topo map of the area, which should hopefully explain things a bit. Red denotes the watershed boundary.


The Mississippi has an average discharge rate of about 16,800 m³/s. The Volga, about 8,000 m³/s. The question is speaking about a river somewhere in between the Volga and the Mississippi; to give an idea about the size, the Volga is about 2 km (1.2 miles) wide at Volgograd (formerly Stalingrad, formely Tsaritsyn), and the Mississippi is about 1 km (0.5 miles) wide at New Orleans. That's way beyond the size of any kind of engineered underground aqueduct, let alone a natural tunnel.

What is the height diffrence between the lake and the outflow? if its more than a few feet it won't last a year. that much moving water will cut any restriction open in no time. the only reason large rivers don't cut is they are slow moving large and above all FLAT rivers. look up the Lake Peigneur incident your lake will empty itself in days.

Might want to read up on underground rivers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subterranean_river

@AlexP I based my numbers for volume off of the kasai and orinoco rivers, which both have catchment areas similar to my own river and are in rainy areas. However, after having reviewed my topographic map I think it's feasible to lower the rainfall based on some rain shadowing followed by relatively gentle topography. It might be more comparable to something like the Yukon's 7k m³/s. If that makes this more realistic I am willing to push the figure down.

@John this is a useful thing to consider. But I would say there is very little height difference between intake and outflow points, and the ingress point is significantly higher than the bottom of the lake bed. As I said, the topography is very flat, and internally I imagine that this river is heavily obstructed in areas so as to not get too fast, and that it likely has formed several channels through which to flow. It's also reasonable to me that it could have eroded by then to an igneous (basalt and/or granite) substrate which does not erode much, which is not the situation in surface rivers

@MaxBird obstructions won't matter that much water flow will carve anything with ease. the ingress point won't stay at the high point.  surface river encounter igneous material all the time its not that difficult to erode. the big question is what is the height of the surface of the lake vs the caves exit, that is what controls the water pressure.

@John this is good to know, is there any way I could change the means of ingress to avoid erosion at the surface? Also, if erosion occurs at this scale, why do normal lakes exist for long periods of time on earth? Does it come down to the ingress point being different?
As for water height, the topography is very flat, and I imagine the majority of the incline would not be very steep. Maybe the point of egress could have a steeper grade? Mainly I needed it to be steep enough for such a system to form initially, but the original point of ingress gets replaced with one that's much flatter/lower.

Lakes are low spots slow moving water, exiting water is not exiting from the bottom, you can think of most lakes as just really wide portions of a river. but in your set up the height of the water collumn combined with the very high amount of flowing water will carve anything. the only way to fix this is drastically change the amount of water flowing through the opening steep water is fine but steep flow plus high volume can carve anything. you have what is among one of the largest rivers on earth.

option 2 put a second outlet, a normal river taking the bulk of the flow, option 3 put the cave ingress higher, so high there is barely any height to the water column, maybe it iven stop during the dry season that will drastically cut the cutting force. Option 4 raise the exits of the cave to nearly the same height as the ingress, that will flood your cave but make it act more like ground water still might be difficult with the amount of water but it will at least last longer.

@John Cool! I'm perfectly happy with making the cave system rather flat horizontally. And I'm now wondering if I mixed up units. Not completely sure because I did what every high school science teacher tells you not to do and forgot to include units on my rough area calculations... if my answer was actually in square kilometers for basin area, that would be another thing to look out for.
I think my original idea has been somewhere along the lines of the ingress point getting lower due to initial erosion and then stabilizing, to justify the erosion needed to form the cave, is that realistic?

YEP
okay, I mixed up square miles of area and square kilometers. Based on new comparisons I think 5k-7k m³/s is much more reasonable. That's embarrassing. I'll go change the numbers in the original post.

Reads like you overspecified the geological history of your lake. What is your priority, from a story-telling perspective: a lake with the dynamics of a kitchen sink? A lake with one secret outlet? A lake without overt outlets? It might be easier to clarify that and let the answers create the geology that goes with it.

Oh, and for a natural lake with human-controlled level (and minimal geological rationale), you may want to (re-)read La demoiselle aux yeux verts. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars%C3%A8ne_Lupin#Overview

@FrançoisJurain good question, the main point is the later need for a canal to connect this watershed up to another large one, but I got fond of the idea. The area is also of religious importance and I thought I might make the caves, filled with thermal pools, mighty rivers, & perhaps a few chambers where sunlight streams in through a cracked basalt roof, a holy site. It seems sufficiently mystical. My overexplanation of the geologic history is mainly because I know underground drainage like this is normally highly irregular, and wanted to give the more reasonable explanation I could think of

So the priority is the volcanic geological context. I'm afraid you have to stick to conventional (meaning existing, RL) geometries for the lake, else it will only last a few yrs : it must empty by spilling over a lid, not through the bottom. The most exotic feature I can think of is a siphon-shaped tunnel which primes spontaneously during the springtime floods, feeding a temporary artesian spring whose waterhead has no obvious connection to the lake. A few dams have safety spillways of this kind in RL.

@FrançoisJurain Oh I was thinking that the point of ingress is at the same level as the lake or near to that level, not subsuface. If it'd help, imagine it as a normal river system which just happens to be covered by a geological feature. Oh, and the river has no seasons. But yeah, any way I can get the lake to have subterranean drainage, ideally through this small flood basalt province, is what I really care about. An
More generally, any way you can make it drain in a way that leaves caves and allows for the surface conditions I described would be excellent.

I'll add a map of the area to better demonstrate what sort of river conditions I'm looking for

The Fontaine de Vaucluse is an exsurgence point of an underground aquifer. At about 40 cubic meters/sec on average during the winter months, it is the world's 5th most abundant spring and has been in existence >= several Kyrs. This gives an idea of how much water can flow in an underground channel w/out sweeping away the entire surrounding bedrock in a few yrs.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fontaine_de_Vaucluse_(spring)

@FrançoisJurain this gives me the impression that the drainage as it's currently conceived is probably not possible... do you have any suggestions for how to have the lake drain without a navigable surface river? Would it be possible for the erosion to have caused repeated collapses that eventually widen the egress channel to a large province of rubble? It seems like a stretch but I do really want to have some way for this to happen, ideally with caves involved.

OK so that's the storytelling requirement: no obviously navigable outlet with >= 5,000 m^3/s input flow. I'm afraid only endorheic lakes achieve that that in RL, i. e. output flow is overwhelmingly by evaporation.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endorheic_lake#List_of_endorheic_lakes

As for an outlet getting buried under rubble: the Columbia river became fordable some centuries ago at Bridge of the Gods, after a mountain slid en masse into the river. Assuming this happened ~1500AD, the river had washed away the rubble into a ~200m wide area of rapids in less than 400yrs, as witnessed by Lewis & Clark. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/03/Bonneville_Landslide%2C_Bridge_of_the_Gods.jpg

@FrançoisJurain do you have any advice for how to balance that? Keeping in mind it's not really a dry climate... maybe I could say evaporation is kicked up a lot geothermally but that sounds kind of out there for the kind of water loss you would need even with an outlet.

Is there a good way for such a river to simply be innavigable?

Sure there is. It is quite plausible (if not 100% true) that the headwaters of the Mississippi river and of the Ohio river are essentially seepage from the bottom of the Great Lakes.  https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Mississippiriver-new-01.png ; together with their north-bank tributaries (LB for the Mississippi, RB for the Ohio), they might qualify as the main outlet of the Great Lakes, yet w/out any (natural) navigable connection.

i.e. it would be plausible to have water leave through a combination of evaporation, seepage, and potentially a smaller, innavigable river? Surface or otherwise.
I'd actually thought of having seepage constitute the main or only outflow, but thought it wouldn't be able to provide sufficient drainage. Honestly I'd much rather have seepage, so if seepage would work, I would be delighted! I'm imagining a large array of seepage outlets like the ones found at 48.2094072,95.9442602 and 48.2335176,95.6836793 in Mongolia which (at a guess) originate from Ulaagchiin Khar lake.

Not an answer, but an slingshot forwards in time to catch "future questions" - your underground river will drain eventually.
But it will also clog with silts over time- and some of the roof may come down.
Which means you have a body of water, that may be in height dependant on:
a) time of year. Snow-melt in winter, drought in summer. This can also be a refill and lowlevel curve.
b) Suddenly refill to the brim and find new rivers through the crater lake city while a mysterious sinkhole appears in the mountains and all mines there get flooded.
c) If the exterior outflow is near the inland seas surface, it may freeze over. Or the outflow may not be visible at all, just a bed of stones where the lake "dissapears" similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danube_Sinkhole .
d) Volcanism and water do not mix. 1l Water that evaporates becomes 1600 l of steam in volume. So if one of your volcanoes is still active, giving off hot water, you are in for the worlds largest steam explosion at some time. We are talking about : "Island gone" size of explosions here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1883_eruption_of_Krakatoa

This is useful, but I believe I did mention that this planet has no axial tilt and no seasons... would seasonality have a large impact?
